# Reference to Grid from RowSelectionModel in ExtJS4

Tags: grid, extjs4, upgrade

In ExtJS version 3, there was a property "grid" in Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel and in version 4 it is missing.

I am using this reference to GridPanel in my functions of class which extends RowSelectionModel.

How can I get this reference in ExtJS 4?

Example of ExtJS 3 code:

```
Ext.extend(MyApp.RowSelectionModel, Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel, {
   ...
   doSomething: function() {
       var referenceToGrid = this.grid;
   }
   ...
});
```

How can I fill the "referenceToGrid" variable with the reference to GridPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the reference in when  defining your SM or you can use ComponentQuery to find your target.

Comment: Thank you, I passed the reference when defining the SM and works OK.